# How to protect an AWS route53 domain where transfer lock is not supported?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

On registering some domains within AWS route53, the console states that Transfer Lock is not supported, which as far as I can tell means anyone can take ownership of the domain and transfer it away and there's nothing I can do about it, which wouldn't be ideal. Below is the advice AWS give, but I've been unable to figure out exactly how to implement what it suggests - (*there doesn't seem to be any knowledge base article that specifically says "if you want to protect a domain, do this..", which seems strange to me...*)

> **Domain locking to prevent unauthorized transfers**
> Not supported. We recommend that you prevent unauthorized transfers by restricting access to the RetrieveDomainAuthCode API action. (When you restrict access to this Route 53 API, you also restrict who can generate an authorization code using the Route 53 console, AWS SDKs, and other programmatic methods.) For more information, see Identity and access management in Amazon Route 53.

The above refers to two documentation links:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_domains_RetrieveDomainAuthCode.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/auth-and-access-control.html

I've created what I think is the correct IAM policy to restrict the RetrieveDomainAuthCode API action, but haven't been able to figure out where to apply it...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "route53domains:RetrieveDomainAuthCode",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:route53domains:::hostedzone/<my-hosted-zone-ID>"
          }
        ]
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: AWS is "deny by default". Therefore, rather than applying a Deny policy somewhere, I think you'd need to avoid using an `Allow` policy that grants the permission. Or, if you grant anyone permission for `route53domains`, then include the above Deny policy too. Be very careful of Admin policies that grant _ALL_ permissions on AWS.